# ResumableUpload with Google Cloud Storage API. How to resume an aborted upload?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

Here's my code:

```
    ...

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(myFilePath));
    var insertObject = service.Objects.Insert(fileName, bucketName, memoryStream, "");

    insertObject.ChunkSize = ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload.MinimumChunkSize;

    insertObject.ProgressChanged += progressChanged;

    Task<IUploadProgress> uploadTask = insertObject.ResumeAsync();

    uploadTask.ContinueWith(MyAction);

}


private void progressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine(obj.BytesSent + "   " + obj.Status);
}
```

It works, but it doesn't resume an aborted upload. It always starts from 0 and sends all bytes again.

Comment: As of version 1.14.0, the Google API v3 .NET Client Library contains a feature to save the UploadUri during a ResumableUpload and to later use that UploadUri to resume the upload in the event of a program restart. There are two ResumableUpload examples in [github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples](http://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the resumable upload protocol. Firstly, Make an initial request to the upload URI that includes the metadata. To initiate a resumable upload, make a *POST* or *PUT* request to the method's /upload URI and add the query parameter '*uploadTrype=resumable*'

Code below is a sample request including query parameter:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable

For this initiating request, the body is either empty or it contains the metadata only; you'll transfer the actual contents of the file you want to upload in subsequent requests.

If the session initiation request succeeds, the API server responds with a *200* *OK* *HTTP* status code.

For more details, please follow this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

Comment: Already read that. However, I'm not sending POST, PUT or anything like that by hand via the API provided by them. So I suppose there's a clean way of doing this using the C# api. So, I'm looking for a working C# example.

Comment: my 2c, don't use the libraries. It's way easier to make your own requests.